How to password protect a quarto dashboard with htaccess
Goal
Create and publish a quarto dashboard on quarto pub website. Password protect it via .htaccess and .htpasswd files.
Example dashboard

An example dashboard is published to quarto pub here:
https://presage.quarto.pub/test/
GitHub repo:
https://github.com/udurraniAtPresage/example-dashboard

Dashboard is not password protected
If you open the dashboard link, you'll see that it does not ask for password. Although, I have this YAML:
---
title: "Test"
format: dashboard
theme: sandstone
resources:
  - .htaccess
  - .htpasswd
---

What am I missing here?
